# Range with leading zero in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, range

I have a form where my users can register to my site.

They fill in theirs birthdate in the form: birthyear, birthmonth and birthday.

So I am using Range to create the select in the form like this:

```
= f.select(:birthmonth, options_for_select((1..12)))
```

But that doesn't start the single digit numbers with a zero like i want: 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10 and so on..

I have even tried this but it didn't work:

```
= f.select(:birthmonth, options_for_select((01..12)))
```

Anybody that know how to get Range to start with leading zeros? Or any other way to do this so I can use it in the validation?:

```
validates_inclusion_of :birthmonth, :in => 1..12
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trouble is that numbers themselves don't have leading zeroes (or, alternately, have an infinite number of leading zeroes that are never printed). To get leading zeroes, you need strings. Fortunately, Ruby comes with this sort of string formatting ability built in.

```
= f.select(:birthmonth, options_for_select((1..12).map {|n| "%02d" % n}))
```

The `%02d` is a formatting specifier that means "pad it with leading zeroes if it's less than two digits."

For validation, you'll need to do the same conversion:

```
validates_inclusion_of :birthmonth, :in => (1..12).map {|n| "%02d" % n}
```

(Thanks to @r-dub for pointing out that bit.)

Comment: You should probably add the correct validates statement to your answer for completeness. validates_inclusion_of :birthmonth, :in => (1..12).map {|n| "%02d" % n}

Comment: It wont validate when i pick a number that starts with a zero. Numbers that starts with one validate though

Comment: Add the validation line I put in my last comment and it should work fine. Your current validation is not the same values as what Chuck put in his answer for the select box.

Comment: This seems to work on the validation part. (1..12).map {|n| ("%02d" % n).to_s}

Comment: It looks like it is because all months will be converted to strings. And it only validates integers

Comment: I edited my last comment with the correct expression that converts them to strings.

Comment: I managed to get it working with Jimmy Bakers solution by changing it to this: 
(1..12).collect{ |i| i < 10 ? 0+i : i }

Comment: You were quicker than me! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can actually just do: `'01'..'12'`

Answer (score 2):

If it is just a presentational issue, you can construct [text, value] pairs and pass them to [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001627):

> Given a container where the elements respond to first and last (such as a two-element array), the "lasts" serve as option values and the "firsts" as option text.

So, something like:

```
options_for_select((1..12).map {|n| ["%02d" % n, n]})
```

That way you should be able to keep your validation logic as is.

Comment: +1 Probably the best answer, though a little late to the party.

Answer (score 2):

Using rjust would make it easier and prettier I guess:

```
(1..12).collect{ |i| i.to_s.rjust(2,'0') }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try padding numbers that are less than 10, like this:

```
= f.select(:birthmonth, options_for_select((1..12).collect{ |i| i < 10 ? "0#{i}" : i }))
```

Comment: Thanks! can i use that in the validation to?

Comment: As a result of this hack, you'll have mixed types in the resulting array, some of the elements being converted to strings, others left as integers. Although it probably wouldn't cause any problem in this particular case, this kind of hacking shouldn't ever be considered as an option, at least not in Ruby (this looks like PHP habit to me).